# The limit of two expressions involving infinite series

Tags: integration, limits, riemann-sum

$$\lim_{h\to 0^+} h \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac {\sin^{2} (nh)} {(nh)^{2}} = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{1}{h} \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac {\sin^{2} (nh)} {(n)^{2}}$$

I tried turning the left side into integral, but it doesn't seem to help. What is the correct way to approach this question?

Comment: Factor out a $1/h^2$ to cancel with the $h$ on the top, no?

Comment: The expressions, without the limit signs, are identical. So then the only question is: Does the limit exist? ( strangely you have a one-sided limit on the left but not on the right).

Comment: @zhw. One possible explanation is that this is part of a chain of computation in a proof, where one tends to use $=$ asymmetrically.  It's common (and unfortunately confusing at times) to write $\cdots = A = B = \cdots$ with the foreknowledge that the expression $B$ exists and implies that $A$ exists, even though we wouldn't write the exact same chain of equalities in reverse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One may write
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{h\to 0^+} h \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac {\sin^{2} (nh)} {(nh)^{2}}&=\lim_{h\to 0^+} h \left[\lim_{M\to \infty}\sum_{n=1}^M \frac {\sin^{2} (nh)} {(nh)^{2}}\right]
\\&=\lim_{h\to 0^+} h \left[\lim_{M\to \infty}\frac1{h^2}\sum_{n=1}^M \frac {\sin^{2} (nh)} {(n)^{2}}\right]
\\&=\lim_{h\to 0^+} h\left[\frac1{h^2}\lim_{M\to \infty}\sum_{n=1}^M \frac {\sin^{2} (nh)} {(n)^{2}}\right]\quad (\text{convergence of the series*})
\\&= \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{1}{h} \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac {\sin^{2} (nh)} {(n)^{2}}
\end{align}
$$ as desired.

$\text{*}$Notice the uniform convergence
$$
\left| \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac {\sin^{2} (nh)} {(n)^{2}}\right|\le  \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac {1} {(n)^{2}}<\infty.
$$

Comment: Why should we notice the uniform convergence?

Comment: @zhw why shouldn't we?

Comment: It doesn't help at all in solving the problem. Also, if you want to note uniform convergence, it would be better to say $$\left |\frac{\sin^2(nh)}{n^2}\right| \le \frac{1}{n^2}$$ for every $n,$ therefore the series converges uniformly by the Weierstrass M test. Saying the absolute value of the value of a  sum is less than some number tells you nothing about uniform convergence.

Comment: The (pointwise) convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac {\sin^{2} (nh)} {n^{2}}$ is sufficient. How would you prove the (pointwise) convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac {\sin^{2} (nh)} {n^{2}}$?

Comment: Same inequality I just wrote.

Comment: *Uniform* convergence is *another* way to obtain *pointwise* convergence.

Answer (score 2):

Forget the limit signs at first, since you don't know the limit exists until you prove it does.

Without the limit signs: For any fixed $h\ne 0,$ both infinite series converge (the summands being on the order of $1/n^2$). The term $h^2,$ which is a constant with respect to the summation, can thus be pulled out of the series on the left, and we see that the two expressions are identical. There is not much going on there.

But you have theses limit signs. What are they doing there? Is part of the problem is to show the limit exists?

The limit does exist, but this requires some work. You mentioned that the expression on the left might have something to do with an integral. Indeed it does. It looks like an "infinite Riemann sum" for

$$\int_0^\infty \left (\dfrac{\sin x}{x}\right )^2\, dx = \frac{\pi}{2}.$$

Like I said, it require some justification to see the desired limit equals the above integral. I'll leave it here for now.

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{h\to 0^+} h \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac {\sin^{2} (nh)} {(nh)^{2}} =\\\lim_{h\to 0^+} h \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac {\sin^{2} (nh)} {n^2h^{2}} =\\ \text{h is constant here } \\\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{h}{h^2} \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac {\sin^{2} (nh)} {(n)^{2}}$$